# Magento: Changing button action

Tags: magento

I want to change the action of Add Product button. I have changed the label by

```
 $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('abc')->__('Export');
```

Can I change its action so that when a user clicks this button he goes to my custom URL?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean "add to cart" button

Comment: No, Add Product button in admin panel. Actually I have designed a custom extension that is similar to the product listing except Add Product button. There will be Export button in the place of Add Product button and it will export products in XML format. Do you understand?? My English is poor, sorry for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following codes

add the below code in `<module>/Block/Adminhtml/<module>/Grid.php`

inside _prepareCollection function

```
 $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv',Mage::helper('your_helper')->__('CSV'));
```

your_helper : maybe your module name

Then add following function in your controller `Controllers/Adminhtml/`

```
 public function exportCsvAction() {
    $fileName = 'your_custom_file.csv';

    $content = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('your_custom_csv_grid')->getCsvFile();

    $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $content);

  }
```

Answer source and more detail [here](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-generate-your-own-reports-in-magento/)